# Writing MATLAB loops to excel

Tags: excel, matlab, loops, matrix

I have been looking for an answer but have not found a correct code!

I am working on a code which results in a **matrix W with dimensions 19x19**; **loop i=1:365.**

I need to **export the matrix to the same excel sheet**. That means **W1 will be written in cell A1, W2 will begin in A20...W3 in A40**...until finishing the loop.

Do you have an idea on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Personally I would concatenate the matrices in MATLAB and then output to Excel as one big chunk. You know the final size of the matrix so it'll be easy to preallocate with, say, [`zeros()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) or [`ones()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) and fill.

Comment: I am quite new in MATLAB and I am not sure on how to concatenate a matrix in a loop and how to save them all together in the same sheet one after the other. Could you give me any tip? Thank you very much excaza!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, since you know the dimensions of your final matrix I would preallocate one large array and export that once your calculations are done. This is much simpler to write than repeated `xlswrite` calls and it's much faster as well.

Take a look at this simplified example:

```
% Set some parameters
nloops = 20; % Number of loops
matrixsize = [5 5]; % Dimensions of the results matrix

% Preallocate output matrix
nrows_output = nloops * matrixsize(1);
outputmatrix = zeros(nrows_output, matrixsize(2));

for ii = 1:nloops
    row_start = ((ii-1) * matrixsize(1)) + 1;
    row_end   = ii * matrixsize(1);

    % Do some calculations
    mycalculationoutput = ii*ones(matrixsize);

    outputmatrix(row_start:row_end,:) = mycalculationoutput;
end

xlswrite('sample.xlsx', outputmatrix);
```

Comment: This simplified example was the perfect tip, the code works perfectly. Thank you very much @excaza!